# Using Restangular, can I use a jsonResultsAdapterProvider when needing to override the id field?

Tags: restangular

I've got a mySql db with non-standard IDs and field names, so I was trying to use both jsonResultsAdapterProvider and setRestangularFields.  Here's the code in my app.config file:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(remoteServiceName);
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({id: 'personID'});
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    if (data.error) {
        return data.error;
    }
    var extractedData = data.result;
    return jsonResultsAdapterProvider.$get().camelizeKeys(extractedData);
});

RestangularProvider.addRequestInterceptor(function(elem, operation, what, url) {
    return jsonResultsAdapterProvider.$get().decamelizeKeys(elem);
});
```

It's all good until I try to do a put/save.  When I look at the request payload within the browser dev tools, it's: `{"undefined":12842}` (but the url is correct, so I know the id is set) If I don't use the ResultsAdapter and change the id field to `Person_ID`, payload looks good, so I know I'm making the right calls to Get and Save the Restangular objects. But for what it's worth, here's the code:

```
$scope.tests = Restangular.all('members').getList().$object;
vm.testEdit = function () {
    $scope.test = Restangular.one('members', 12842).get().then(function(test) {
        var copy = Restangular.copy(test);
        copy.title = 'xxxx';

        copy.put();  // payload was: undefined: 12842
    });
}

// I also tried customPUT...
// copy.customPUT(copy, '', {}, {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
```

I tried "fixing" the id other ways too, too.  like this:

```
Restangular.extendModel('members', function(model) {
  model.id = model.personID;
  return model;
});
```

but that messed up the urls, causing missing ids. And I tried `getIdFromElem`, but it only got called for my objects created with `Restangular.one()`, not with `Restangular.all()`

```
Restangular.configuration.getIdFromElem = function(elem) {
    console.log('custom getIdFromElem called');
    if (elem.route === 'members') {  // this was never true
        return elem[personID];
    }
};
```

It seems like Restangular needs to substitute 'personID' most of the time, but maybe it needs 'Person_ID' at some point during the Save? Any ideas on what I could try to get the Save working?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!  The problem was in my config code and in the way I was decamelizing.  Because of inconsistencies in my db field names (most use underscores, but some are already camelCase), I was storing the server's original `elem` names in an array within the `jsonResultsAdapterProvider`.  But since I was calling `jsonResultsAdapterProvider.$get().camelizeKeys(extractedData);` within the interceptors, I was reinstantiating the array each time I made a new request.  So, the undefined in the PUT request was coming from my `decamelizeKeys()` method.

My updated config code fixed the problem:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(remoteServiceName);
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({id: 'personID'});
var jsonAdapter = jsonResultsAdapterProvider.$get();
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
  if (data.error) {
    return data.error;
  }
  var extractedData = data.result;
  // return extractedData;
  return jsonAdapter.camelizeKeys(extractedData);
});

RestangularProvider.addRequestInterceptor(function(elem, operation, what, url) {
  return jsonAdapter.decamelizeKeys(elem);
});
```